# How to add an existing csv file as new worksheet in existing excel workbook via PowerShell script

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have to create a PowerShell script , which will pick the csv and import this csv as new excel worksheet in already existing Excel workbook.
I tried multiple solutions, but it is only creating a new workbook from the csv instead of adding it in existing one.

```
$excelname = "F:\testexcel.xlsx"
$csvname = "F:\main.csv" 
$excelapp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb2 = $excelapp.workbooks.open($csvname,$null,$true)
$wb1 = $excelapp.workbooks.open($excelname) 
$worksheet = $excelapp.worksheets.add($csvname)
$wb1.sheets.item($worksheet.name).move($wb1.sheets.item(2) )
$wb2.close($false)
$wb1.Save()
$wb1.Close($false,$null,$null)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelapp)
```

Also to mention, this can not be done from import-excel module , as being suggested by my stakeholder.

Comment: Please take a look at the great module [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/).

Comment: Please format your code as code an not as an image

Comment: @Nicicalu, i have edited it now.

Comment: @Olaf, i have to do it traditional way, and can not do it by importexcel, as i mentioned in my question above.

Comment: @sakki Why? What counts? What is important? The way to reach a goal or the goal?  ;-)